# Algebraic numbers in Z3

Tags: z3, z3py

The following code sets some Z3 constraints for x,y that are satisfied (only) by:
x = sqrt(2) and y = -sqrt(2).

```
x, y = Reals('x y')
s = Solver()
s.add( x*x == 2 )
s.add( x>0)
s.add( y*y == 2 )
s.add( y<0)
s.check()
m = s.model()
val_x = m.get_interp(x)
val_y = m.get_interp(y)

print(f"The solutions are: x={val_x} and y={val_y}")
print(f"The defining polynomial of x has integer coefficients", val_x.poly(), " and root index ", val_x.index())
print(f"The defining polynomial of y has integer coefficients", val_y.poly(), " and root index ", val_y.index())
```

The output is:

```
The solutions are: x=1.4142135623? and y=-1.4142135623?

the defining polynomial of x has integer coefficients [-2, 0, 1]  and root index  0

the defining polynomial of y has integer coefficients [-2, 0, 1]  and root index  0
```

It thus appear that the `.index()` function, which is supposed to extract the index of an algebraic number, does not work: Both $sqrt(2)$ and $- sqrt(2)$ are given the same index.

I have reported this issue in the Z3 github ([link](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/5807)) but unfortunately the devs do not have the bandwidth to solve this issue.

I had a look at the python code for the `.index()` function (path z3/lib.z3.py):

```
def index(self):
    return Z3_algebraic_get_i(self.ctx_ref(), self.as_ast())
```

which just calls:

```
def Z3_algebraic_get_i(a0, a1, _elems=Elementaries(_lib.Z3_algebraic_get_i)):
  r = _elems.f(a0, a1)
  _elems.Check(a0)
  return r
```

which basically (?) calls the method `Z3_algebraic_get_i` of the Z3 library in the C language.

I am not familiar myself with C, so I am seeking some help:

**QUESTION** is the `Z3_algebraic_get_i` function of the C Z3 library actually working, or it's just Python?

Thanks

---

EDIT: This is the source code of the C function from [here](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/api_algebraic.cpp)

```
    unsigned Z3_API Z3_algebraic_get_i(Z3_context c, Z3_ast a) {
        Z3_TRY;
        LOG_Z3_algebraic_get_i(c, a);
        RESET_ERROR_CODE();
        CHECK_IS_ALGEBRAIC(a, 0);
        algebraic_numbers::manager & _am = am(c);
        algebraic_numbers::anum const & av = get_irrational(c, a);
        return _am.get_i(av);
        Z3_CATCH_RETURN(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/pull/5888, so make sure to update z3 if you still see this issue. I'm not sure what the first version of z3 to have the fix was, but I just upgraded to 4.11.2.0, and it's working now.

Also worth noting: roots are 1-indexed in z3.

Answer (score 2):

This indeed seems to be a bug in z3py; and I strongly suspect in the python bindings only. However, fixing it will take intimate knowledge of the code-base, even though it might be a simple thing at the end. You did the right thing by reporting it to the developers. It's unfortunate that they don't have the bandwidth to rectify the issue.

However, I can offer a hack, which can provide a workaround till there's a proper fix, if ever. Define:

```py
def get_root_obj_index(ar):
    return Int(ar.sexpr().split()[-1][:-1])
```

Now you can change the last two lines of your program to say:

```py
print(f"The defining polynomial of x has integer coefficients", val_x.poly(), " and root index ", get_root_obj_index(val_x))
print(f"The defining polynomial of y has integer coefficients", val_y.poly(), " and root index ", get_root_obj_index(val_y))
```

And this prints:

```
The defining polynomial of x has integer coefficients [-2, 0, 1]  and root index  2
The defining polynomial of y has integer coefficients [-2, 0, 1]  and root index  1
```

This does the right thing for your *particular* example, and I think it'll do the right thing in general; so long as the result is a root-object. The hack is to print the object as an s-expr, which shows it as a root-object and extract the index value. Of course, you might want to be careful and do some checking on the result of `sexpr()` to make sure it indeed does look like a root-object first, and if not, throw an error or return some default value.

I should *emphasize* that this is a hack, and should be used sparingly and only with care; but it can help you if no one steps up to fix the corresponding bug in z3py.

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful indeed. For more general usage, I think I implement a procedure that transforms a s-expr in a tree (using the fact that the s-expr is well parenthesised). Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Yes, proper parsing and making sure it’s indeed a root-obj first would go a long way. Best of luck!